# problem with LD_PRELOAD

Tags: libc, pwntools, error, error-messages

[image: I try LD_PRELOAD]
Hell0!!!
I try ld_preload by pwntools and take it...
How can I fix this problem???

Comment: Please post text information as text instead of an image.